# adding class jQuery to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

i just need a jquery code or javascript code to

i have a menu tabs this tabs contain ( ul > li > a ) i need when i'm click in this 
( a ) add class in another (carousel_inner ul )

html

```
<ul>
                            <li><a href="#your-tab-id-1">one</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#your-tab-id-2">two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#your-tab-id-3">three</a></li>
                         </ul>
                         <div class="content_holder">
                          <div id="your-tab-id-1">
                            <div class='carousel_container'>
                              <div class='left_scroll'><img src='left.png' /></div>
                                <div class='carousel_inner'>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href='#'><img src='item1.png' /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'><img src='item2.png' /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'><img src='item3.png' /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'><img src='item4.png' /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'><img src='item5.png' /></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple anchor tags matching the selector. Use:

```
$('.carousel_inner > ul > li > a').addClass('yourClass');
```

Comment: thanks, but can i specify where the class add and when click in another .carousel_inner > ul > li > a remove it and add it in another one